# Re-Queue/Re-Try a message on failure

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, enterprise-integration

I receive a message via a message queue.
The message should be persisted and sent to a SOAP endpoint.

When that SOAP endpoint is not available, delivery to that endpoint should be retried until
it is sucessfully delivered.
Retries should happen with a delay of 10 seconds.

I tried several ways to achieve this.

onException, errorHandler(noErrorHandler), transacted(), rollback()....

What finally works is this.

```
from(incomingQueue)
                .routeId("incomingQueue")
                .log("sending to partner")
                .wireTap(persistOutgoingUri)
                .doTry()
                .to(sendViaSoap)
                .log("Got Response for SOAP: ${body}")
                .doCatch(IOException.class)
                .log("SOAP delivery failed, requeuing the message...")
                .delay(10000)
                .to(incomingQueue);
```

But I wonder, if that is the idiomatic way to do it in apache camel.

Comment: This question is off-topic and should either be re-worded or closed. Asking for the _best_ way to accomplish a particular task is going to elicit opinion-based answers rather than fact-based ones since it's a relative measure based almost entirely on your specific use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I re-worded the question.
I am not interested in an opnion-based answer, but the correct way of using the apache-camel api to handle exceptions and retries.